# How to encode an uploaded image using base64 and create a brand new PNG image by decoding it?

Tags: python, django

Currently, I created a Django html page that'll allow a user to upload an image. Images are restricted to only JPG, JPEG, PNG and SVG. If uploaded correctly, the image is stored as in a png extension. After this, I want to grab the path and encode it using base64. Using this string, I want to then create a brand new image which should hold a PNG extension and then store it in the database. How should I do this? Or better yet, is there a better way to do it? I feel that converting an existing png image to a new png image **again** might be tedious. Please do help.

Code below:

**validators.py**

```
def validate_file_extension(value):
    import os
    from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
    ext = os.path.splitext(value.name)[1]  # [0] returns path+filename
    valid_extensions = ['.jpg', '.png', '.jpeg', '.svg']
    if not ext.lower() in valid_extensions:
        raise ValidationError(u'Unsupported file extension.')
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
import os
from PIL import Image
from datetime import date
import datetime
from .validators import validate_file_extension
import base64

def get_directory_path(instance, filename):
    today = date.today()
    t = datetime.datetime.now() 
    day, month, year = today.day, today.month, today.year
    hour, minutes, seconds = t.hour, t.minute, t.second
    filename = str(day) + str(month) + str(year) + str(hour) + str(minutes) + str(seconds) + '.png'
    dir = 'media'
    path = '{0}/{1}'.format(dir, filename)
    return path

 class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(upload_to = get_directory_path, default = 'media/sample.png', validators=[validate_file_extension])
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    **@property 
    def image_url(self):
        with open(self.image.path, "rb") as imageFile:
            string = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())
        with open(self.image.path, "wb") as fh:
            fh.write(str.decode('base64'))
            return fh**  #I'm not sure about this property method and was just experimenting.
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

from myapp.models import Image

class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Image upload form"""
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        exclude = ('created_date',)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db import models
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, CreateView
from myapp.forms import ImageForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin

class BaseView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "base.html"

class ImageView(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = "insert_image.html"
    form_class = ImageForm
    success_message = "Image uploaded successfuly"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("base")
```

**insert.html**

```
<body>

    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
    </form>

    <p> Required format: PNG, JPEG, JPG, SVG </p>

</body>
```

**result.html**

```
    {% if messages %}
        <ul class="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}
             <li {% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}

    <button> <a href = '{% url "insert_image" %}' style="text-decoration: none;"> Return </button> </a>

</body>
```

Comment: Why do you want to store images in your database?

Comment: Please don't store binary data in the database. For not very small streams, this will slow down the system: https://habiletechnologies.com/blog/better-saving-files-database-file-system/

Comment: @IainShelvington then what would be the best way to store images then? Suppose, it's like a user profile page, and if a user wants to see his profile picture, you need to view the image right? Do you have any other better method though? I just want to read the encode the current images in the database and decode them into a new png image.

Comment: @Retro_coder: Django already *has* a solution for that: an **`ImageField`**: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField It just stores it in the media directory.

Comment: @Retro_coder storing on the file system is preferable, the blog that Willem linked has information that may help you. Django's `FileFIeld` or `ImageField` will handle serving the file from the file system.

Comment: Think of it like this: most databases store data on a disk, when you query the database for a single row containing an image you are adding the overhead of querying the database to reading the image off disk (not to mention using a DB thread for no reason). If it's just a file on disk there is no overhead

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Then how do you usually store images then? Do you convert the binary data to string? If so, how do you retrieve the image back if a user wishes to see it?

Comment: @IainShelvington Oh I see. I'm still figuring it out. But for now, I just want to encode my images using base64 and store it in the database. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Just asking, what do you think about the property method in models.py under class Image? Does it correctly encode and decode the image?